# Is this derivative correct ?- solved

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I want to compute

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[ \int_t^{\tau}e^{-r(s-t)}(-pc) \,ds\right]$$ First, I know that I can just solve the integral and take the derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[ \int_t^{\tau}e^{-r(s-t)}(-pc) \,ds\right]=\frac{d}{dt}\left[ \frac{-pc}{r}\left(1-e^{-r(\tau-t)}\right)\right]$$
$$=pc\cdot e^{-r(\tau-t)}$$

however, I want to solve it "straight away" using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. However, I must be doing something wrong because I obtain the following:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[ \int_t^{\tau}e^{-r(s-t)}(-pc) \,ds\right]=-e^{-r(t-t)}(-pc)-pc\int_t^{\tau} \frac{d}{dt}e^{-r(s-t)}ds$$
$$=pc-pc\cdot r\int_t^{\tau} e^{-r(s-t)}ds$$
$$=pc+pc [e^{-r(\tau-t)}-1]$$
$$=pc\cdot e^{-r(\tau-t)}$$

**Comment:** Initially, I did an algebra mistake and wasn't getting the same result for the second equation. Now it seems to be right. The magic of typing in latex code :). Already wrote the question though. So tell me if the way I compute this second derivative is correct according to you.

Comment: You are using the wrong formula $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}u(t,s)ds=\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,s)ds$$ instead of $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}u(t,s)ds=\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,s)ds+b'(t)u(t,b(t))-a'(t)u(t,a(t))$$ In your case, $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_t^\tau u(t,s)ds=\int_t^\tau\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,s)ds-u(t,t)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dt} \int_t^\tau e^{-r(s-t)}(-pc)ds$

$= \frac{d}{dt}\left[- \int_\tau^t e^{-r(s-t)}(-pc)ds\right]$

$= \frac{d}{dt} \int_\tau^t pc \cdot e^{rt} \cdot e^{-rs}ds $

$= pc \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \left [ e^{rt}\cdot \int_\tau^t f(s)ds\right], $

where $f(s) = e^{-rs}$. Try using the fundamental theorem now.

This doesn't really make it much easier, because you'll still have to evaluate the integral when using the product rule.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Note that $f(s)$ actually depends on $t$!

Comment: I realized that so I updated my answer. You need to use the product rule too